# Centering a Tframe within a TTabSheet;

Tags: delphi, tframe

I have a delphi application that used a `PageControl` with a number of `TabSheets`.  I also create new `TabSheets` at runtime and populate them with instances of predefined frames.  These frames work well, except for the cosmetic problem of not centering on the `TabSheet`.  I have tried to use `Frame.Align := alClient`, but that didn't do it.  The relevant code follows:

```
CreateNewPage(3);
NewLimitedChoiceFrame := TLimitedChoiceFrame.Create(NewInputPage);
NewLimitedChoiceFrame.Parent := NewInputPage;
```

`CreateNewPage` creates a new instance of a `TabSheet` and makes the `PageControl` it's owner and parent.  The result is assigned to the global variable `NewInputPage`.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers ;-) This comment will destroy itself in few minutes, please do not respond to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To centre a control in its parent do this:

```
procedure CentreControl(Control: TControl);
begin
  Control.Left := (Control.Parent.ClientWidth-Control.Width) div 2;
  Control.Top := (Control.Parent.ClientHeight-Control.Height) div 2;
end;
```

Call this function, passing the frame. Obviously you need to wait until you've assigned the parent before doing so.

If the page control can be re-sized at runtime, add a call to this function from the tabsheet's OnResize event. Or, as [NGLN points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614453/anchors-akcenter) simply set the control's `Anchors` to `[]` and the VCL framework will take care off centring the control when its parent is resized.

Comment: +1 To keep the control centered when the page control can be resized at runtime, then `Control.Anchors = []` will do too.

Comment: @NGLN I don't think so. To keep it centred, Left and Top need to be updated on each resize.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, NGLN is right (checked for XE2). If Align is set to alNone and no anchors are set, the control is centered inside its parent control. You can check the code in TWinControl.ArrangeControl.