# Anchors := [akCenter]?

Tags: delphi, alignment, anchor, centering

How can I center a control within its parent? And how to keep it centered when the parent resizes?

I know I could write a `Parent.OnResize` event handler to move the control manually, but not all container components have an `OnResize` event, and I would like to do this automatically.

Is there an `akCenter` anchor?

Comment: Changing layout in OnResize event would result in flickering. We need to recalculate layout before form redraw occurs.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The anchor `akCenter` does not exist. But you can mimic `akRelative` by setting the anchors property empty which results in relative movement of the control when the parent resizes. Combining that with centered placement will result in a centered-alike "anchor".

To center horizontally at designtime:

- In the IDE, choose the context menu of the control (right click),
- *Position > Align > Horizontal > Center in Window*,
- Set `Anchors.akLeft := False`, `Anchors.akRight := False` in the object inspector,
- Et voilà : `akHorzCenter`.

The same goes for vertical, in which case you set `akTop` and `akBottom` false. To center in both directions: `Anchors := []`.

[image: Animation of akRelative in action]

Disclaimer: I have not found documentation of this anchors usage and I do not know whether this is the intended functioning, but it works very nice in D7 as well as in XE2.

Comment: +1 This is neat and thank you for teaching me something new that I did not know.