# Is there a way to change the anchor position for an icon of a marker

Tags: delphi, gmlib

I have larger pictures i want to use as icons in a list of markers but the default anchor position is bottom center and i would like it to be middle center, is there a way to do this with an marker icon in the gmlib map ?

Comment: TMarker don't have any property to establish the anchor yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Anchors.akCenter:= true;` does not exist, but if you remove the akLeft and akRight it will center horizontally.

`Anchors:= [];` should do the trick.

See this answer: [Anchors := [akCenter]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614453/anchors-akcenter)